# Would it be possible to grab my Spiritual Weapon and make a melee attack with it?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, weapons, melee-combat

If I cast *spiritual weapon*, would it be possible to grab it and make a melee attack with it?

Of course the attack would take my action and I would have to use my strength modifier to hit because I am physically swinging it, but is it possible to do that? Could I even just grab it and run thirty feet, then release it so it can move and attack for my bonus action?

Comment: Related: [Can you pick up an ally's spiritual weapon and use it as your own?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/115209/14878)

Comment: Related: [Can the Spiritual Weapon spell be used as cover?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/204975/23547)

Answer (score 13):

## No, you can't use *spiritual weapon* as a melee weapon

This is a really cool idea but unfortunately doesn't work by RAW or RAI.

#### Melee Attack

[Spells only do what they say](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/107647/48759) and no part of *spiritual weapon* indicates that you can use it as a melee weapon.

*Spiritual Weapon* states:

> You create a floating weapon that lasts for the duration or until you cast this spell again.

So I can certainly see where this idea came from. However it specifies you make a *melee spell attack* as a *bonus action*. So that is the only attack it can make.

#### Regarding movement

> As a bonus action, you can move the weapon up to 20 feet and repeat the attack against a creature within 5 feet of it.

The only way to move *spiritual weapon* is to use your bonus action to move it 20ft. There is no way to gain additional bonus actions in a single turn so you can't move it further than this.

---

#### Potential Homebrew

*WARNING THIS IS UNTESTED.* I am not recommending this but providing it as a base if you wish to homebrew this into your game.

The second part of your question has potential for homebrew.

> Could I even just grab it and run thirty feet, then release it so it can move attack for my bonus action?

Using your action this way seems like a balanced option to me. Allowing movement shouldn't be too game-breaking but would be definitely not supported by RAW.

**However...**

There may be some unintended consequences to allowing this. As Rubiksmoose points out, the weapon is not a physical object at all and cannot be grabbed. If you can grab it so can other creatures. This completely changes the nature of the spell. Does it now occupy a space? Can it be damaged? etc.

As *spiritual weapon* can take any form you wish, allowing it to be a physical object would bring it fairly close to the 14th level illusion schools *Illusory Reality* feature. Though not as powerful this is still extremely strong for a 1st level spell and you would want to limit how it could be used.

The first question allowing you to use your action to attack with spiritual weapon is broken and should not be allowed. Cast at first level this may not seem like a big deal. *1d8 + Spellcasting Modifier* is equal or less than most melee weapons you would normally be wielding.

The problem is when casting at higher levels, at 5th level *spiritual weapon* deals 3d8 force damage. Allowing attacks with action and bonus action would mean 6d8 force damage per turn, potentially up to 60d8 over the duration for a single 5th level spell slot.

Allowing it to be used as a weapon also exposes you to the question of making *attacks of opportunity* with it. [*Spiritual Weapon* cannot make *attacks of opportunity*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/132704/48759) by RAW and allowing this would only exacerbate the problem with this house rule.

Comment: So here's some concerns with your homebrew: RAW the weapon is not a physical object at all and cannot be grabbed. Changing this raises some complicated questions. Does it now occupy it's space? Also if you can grab your weapon to move it why couldn't your opponent? I think the house rule is a well intentioned attempt to find a way to realize OP's ideas but I just think it will introduce a lot more problems.

Answer (score -3):

I would allow it as a special effect. It would still have the same game mechanics, but if you were to hold it in your left hand, you could have the cool factor of having say, a warhammer in one hand, spiritual weapon in the other. The spiritual weapon still only attacks as a bonus action, it is just temporarily occupying the same space as you. The mechanics of the spell don't change, merely the aesthetics for role-playing. If you move more than 20 feet in the round, the spiritual weapon will be left behind.

Another fun idea is if you combine it with a Shadow Blade or Flame Blade (if you are multiclassed). You could use an action to hit with the flame blade, then bonus attack to hit with spiritual weapon as if you were dual wielding. Since Spiritual Weapon doesn't require concentration, you can do this at the cost of two 2nd level slots.

The scene from Avengers Endgame comes to mind. Thor dual wielding Stormbreaker and Mjolner. Now imagine a Tempest Cleric/Storm Sorcerer using a battleaxe, then summoning a spiritual weapon shaped like a Warhammer. With the axe, you can use Booming Blade. Then as a bonus action, send Spiritual Mjolner 20 feet to make an attack (simulating Thor throwing it). On your next turn, another Booming Blade, the hammer comes back to you and you can swing it with your off-hand (bonus action).